# How can I determine the memory used by a collection of objects (QGraphicsScene) and by a QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, memory

I am using `QGraphicsView` / `QGraphicsScene` to manage items inherited from `QGraphicsItem`.

I will have to use large number of items possibly, on a very large scene, on a device with limited memory.

For benchmarking, I need to find how much memory the `QGraphicsScene` with all the elements takes, and also how much memory the small `QGraphicsView` window takes.

```
int inputMem = 0;
for (int i = 0; i< myView->scene()->items().size(); ++i)
{
    Item* item = new Item(*(dynamic_cast<Item*>(myView->scene()->items().at(i))));
    inputMem += sizeof(*item);
    delete item;
}
```

Would this be realistic ?

At the moment, my Item contains no pointer to an outside object (but can contain objects such as `QString` or `QPixmap` or `QSvg`)

My (wild) guess, regarding `QGraphicsView` memory size, is that it would be somewhat proportional to the size of the view, and with the screen resolution... and may not depend on the items added ?

How can that be determined... and if my assumption is not true, how can I determine the memory used b a `QGraphicsView`, since it can contain partial objects ?

How can I determine the amount of memory used by each ?

Comment: Don´t take the size of `&item`, but `*item`. And just allocating a large number and watching the difference of memory usage for the whole program often is more realistic

Comment: thanks i saw the mistake in using the address instead of value -  edited

Comment: thanks i can try checking the memory used by the program and comparing with what my loop shows.